# jquery - syntax error on array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, syntax-error

was wondering if anyone could tell me what was wrong with this:

```
function cat_autocomplete(){
    var categoryTags = ["boots>black","boots>brown>boys>blue","clothes>small_men>scarfs>blue","boots","boots>brown>boys","boots>brown","ties>casual","clothes","coats","clothes>girls","boots>brown>girls","clothes>small_men>hats","jackets","clothes>mens","clothes>red","boots>brown>red","clothes>small_men>scarfs","shoes","clothes>small_men","ties>smart","ties","clothes>womens"];
    $( "input[name=category]" ).autocomplete({
        source: categoryTags
    });
}
```

the error on firebug is with categoryTags... i cant see anything wrong.

edit : full code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function cat_autocomplete(){
    var categoryTags = ["boots>black","boots>brown>boys>blue","clothes>small_men>scarfs>blue","boots","boots>brown>boys","boots>brown","ties>casual","clothes","coats","clothes>girls","boots>brown>girls","clothes>small_men>hats","jackets","clothes>mens","clothes>red","boots>brown>red","clothes>small_men>scarfs","shoes","clothes>small_men","ties>smart","ties","clothes>womens"];
    $( "input[name=category]" ).autocomplete({
        source: categoryTags
    });
}
function prod_autocomplete(){
    var productTags = ["clothes>small_men>hats","boots>black","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>mens","clothes>small_men","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats","clothes>small_men>hats"];
    $( "input[name=product]" ).autocomplete({
        source: productTags
    }); 
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    prod_autocomplete();
    cat_autocomplete();
});
</script>
```

edit : php file

```
<?php 
session_start();
try{
    require_once "../../classes/config.php";
    require_once "../../classes/database.php";
    require_once "../../classes/categories.php";
    require_once "../../classes/global_data.php";
    $cOb = new config();
    $cOb->set_mode(0);
    $cOb->set_table_prefix( 'lazy' );
    $cOb->dbdetails(array( 'dbuser' => '', 'dbpass' => '', 'dbserver' => 'localhost', 'dbname' => 'test' ) );
    $cOb->set_srv_root( 'C:/wamp/www/ecom_framework/' );
    $cOb->set_sec_root( 'http://localhost/ecom_framework/' );
    $cOb->set_web_root( 'http://localhost/ecom_framework/' );
    $con = Database::getInstance( $cOb );
    ob_start(); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cat_autocomplete(){
        var categoryTags = [<?php
            $con = Database::getInstance();
            $sql = "SELECT cat_id FROM `" . $cOb::$table_prefix . "_tbl_category` ORDER BY cat_name";
            $re = $con->query($sql);
            $str = '';
            while( $ob = $re->fetch_object() ) {
                $str .= '"' . categories::get_breadcrum_from_id( $ob->cat_id, '>' ) . '",'; 
            }
            echo rtrim( $str, ',' ) . "];\n";
            ?>
        $( "input[name=category]" ).autocomplete({
            source: categoryTags
        });
    }
    function prod_autocomplete(){
        var productTags = [<?php
            $con = Database::getInstance();
            $sql = "SELECT cat_id, pd_name FROM `" . $cOb::$table_prefix . "_tbl_product` ORDER BY pd_name";
            $re = $con->query($sql);
            $str = '';
            while( $ob = $re->fetch_object() ) {
                $str .= '"' . categories::get_breadcrum_from_id( $ob->cat_id, '>' ) . '",'; 
            }
            echo rtrim( $str, ',' );
            ?>];
        $( "input[name=product]" ).autocomplete({
            source: productTags
        }); 
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        prod_autocomplete();
        cat_autocomplete();
    });
    </script>
    <?php 
    $content = ob_get_clean(); 
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    echo $content;
    exit;
}catch(Exception $err){
    die( $cOb->mode( $err->getMessage() ) );    
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Firebug doesn't tell me of any errors.

Comment: syntax error
http://localhost/ecom_framework/admin/javascript/autocomplete.js.php
Line 3

Comment: Your `localhost` link won't take us anywhere. Do you have this published to the Web?

Comment: did you include jQuery.js? the jQueryUI? because, it's working when I tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/fJkgv/)

Comment: [updated, still working](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/fJkgv/1/)

Comment: yeah, just checked all sources lead to the files.

Comment: Include the specific error message in the question. It may be possible to deduce the problem just from that. "an error" isn't very useful.

Comment: ok i copied and pasted the output from the dynamic file into a js file and it works... ill add my php file into the question..1 min

Comment: sorry, my fault, just found that I completely overlooked when I copied from main file i left in the `<script type="text/javascript">
    function cat_autocomplete(){`wont work with the <script> tags. Sorry all

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the var keyword before categoryTags. 
I think your problem is Javascript scope. 
By using the var keyword before initializing categoryTags, it belongs withing the scope of the cat_autocompete function. 
However, $().autocomplete is not within that function's scope. 
$().autocomplete is looking for a categoryTags within its scope and not finding it there looks for it within the window scope. 
By removing the var keyword within the cat_autocomplete function, categoryTags will be tied to the window scope and be available to $().autocomplete.

```
function cat_autocomplete(){
 categoryTags = ["foo","bar"];
 $( "input[name=category]" ).autocomplete({
  source: categoryTags
 });
}
```

Caveat to all above: littering the global namespace is not a great way to approach things. 
However, outlining a better way is out of scope for this answer.
Hope this helps.